# How can I change the charachter skin in godot?

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

I want to change the charachter skin in a different scene, but I don't know how to do this
I want to make the player able to do this in a different scene and save it between scenes and make it able to select even if you quit the game and opened it again

Comment: What do you mean by "character skin"? Please explain, preferably with an example. You can edit your question.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want but I'll give you the basics anyway: 1. If you want something to persist across a scene change, you need to put it on an autoload. 2. If you want something to persist even when the game is closed and opened again, you need logic to save it and load it from a file. *And you can guess, where you would put that logic… In an autoload!* The details of how to save, load and apply your "character skin", depends on what a "character skin" is. Hopefully this can get you started.

Comment: You can check out the docs about autoloads - https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html